# failed to upload zip file: Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource

Tags: google-cloud-functions, github-actions

I want to automatically deploy cloud functions via GitHub Actions

This is my `deploy-cloud-functions.yml` file

```yaml
name: Deploy Cloud Functions

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - feat/queue

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions:
      contents: 'read'
      id-token: 'write'

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Authenticate
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v1'
      with:
        workload_identity_provider: 'projects/<number>/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/<name>/providers/<name>'
        service_account: 'test@test.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

    - name: Deploy Cloud Functions
      uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions@v1
      with:
        name: myName
        runtime: nodejs16
        entry_point: myName
        source_dir: ./functions
```

But it throws me an error during `Deploy Cloud Functions` step.

```
Error: google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions failed with: failed to upload zip file: Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).
```

This is the list of permissions I added to my service account

```
Cloud Functions Service Agent
Service Account OpenID Connect Identity Token Creator
Service Account Token Creator
Service Account User
Workload Identity User
```

Could you please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

While creating a service account in the Cloud Console it will create all the services automatically including service accounts. Here when you delete or change the default settings; you may face the issue which Cloud Function which needs iam.serviceAccount.getAccessToken permission. This will generate an access token for the service account to deploy Cloud Functions.

```
Name: service-<account-id>@test.iam.gserviceaccount.com 
Role: roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
```

Also you can  add running following command:

Gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding  \

-- member=”serviceAcconut : test@test.iam.gserviceaccount.com” 
-- role=”roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator”

Please check [gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding)  document.

Please recheck your correct value for ‘Workload_identity_provider’ and if you are still facing any issue you can add additional debugging steps to the GitHub action workflow.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the error message is a red herring. Your service account already has the `iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken` permission via the `Workload Identity User` role among others.

Check your Workload Identity Provider and corresponding service account policy binding in Google Cloud. Are the GitHub organization and repository names correct?

I once had the exact same error and it was because I had renamed the GitHub repository and forgot to update the name of the principalSet in the policy binding.